# Axios + Sequelize ValidationError = no request or response objects in promise catch block? How to handle?

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, axios

Typically, I have Axios calls that look something like this:

```
api.post('/users/add', (req, res, next) => {
  Users.create(req.body).then(userResult => {
    // misc code here
    return res.json(userResult)
  }).catch((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle the error by sending to the application error handler
      next(err);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that req, res, and next do not seem to exist if the error is a Sequelize validation error. So I add a check inside the IF like this:

```
if (err) {
  if (err instanceof Sequelize.ValidationError) {
    // i've tried a lot here and am stuck as to what to do
  } else {
    // handle other errors
  }
}
```

I can inspect the error just fine once I'm in that inner IF, but I don't know what to do to get a response back out to the calling browser. I also can't call next() and bubble up the error to my regular error handler since it doesn't recognize next(). And if I could, the items I usually use from req or res aren't available.

I've gone over all of the documentation on the Sequelize website, pored over the issue queue, searched here on stackoverflow, and can't seem to find the same problem. I assume, therefore, the solution is something simple that is just a gap in my knowledge. Please enlighten me. How do I either get this to bubble up to my general error handler or return a response to the browser from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not redefine `req`, `res`, and `next` in the catch. They will be accessible from the parent scope but by including them in the catch they will be undefined as a then/catch will only have a single argument.

```
/* create a POST route. for /users/add requests it will 
   call a function passing in req, res, next() */
api.post('/users/add', (req, res, next) => { // this syntax creates an "arrow function"
  /* note that it's probably a bad idea to just 
     pass in the request.body without sanitizing */
  return Users.create(req.body)    // call Sequelize and get a Promise
    .then((userResult) => {        // success, userResult will be the new user
      return res.json(userResult); // use res.json() to send to client
    })
    .catch((err) => {              // create failed
      return next(err);            // pass the err along to next()
    });
});
```

If you want to write the same code with `async/await` which lets you write asynchronous code in a synchronous syntax. When you add `async` the function will automatically return a Promise. Using `await` will wait for a Promise to resolve (or throw an error) without going into indendentation hell (in this case the result of the user creation).

```
api.post('/users/add', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await Users.create(req.body);
    return res.json(userResult);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So do I actually have two promises going? I assume api.post is one too, is it not? I'm trying to figure out how to send the client a response from the error.

Oh, wait. I see you used next(), which, since you pointed out I was redefining it, must mean you're calling the one defined in the api.post call. In which case, I suppose the req and res may also be available. Sheesh. I'll go see what I can do with that.

Comment: No... `api.post()` defines a `POST` route, when it is requested the `req` and `res` objects are passed in along with the `next()` function. Inside this function you are calling Sequelize to create a `User` record that returns a Promise. That promise resolves the `userResult` which you pass to the `res.json()` function to return to the client. If the Promise is rejected then the `.catch()` is called with the `err` that you can pass along in the `next()` function. By adding `req`, `res`, and `next` to your header they become undefined because the `catch()` does not include them.

Comment: Think of `res.json()` and `next()` as callbacks - nothing is sent to the client until you call them regardless of if there are Promises, async callbacks, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarifications. I have everything working now and made notes in my code so I don't forget lessons learned. I've been programming for 20 years but am new to this re-worked Javascript. It's nothing like what it was when I was in college. I sort of jumped in starting with VueJS and have had to work backwards back to NodeJS and vanilla Javascript. I really need to find time to step back and look at both of those independently and really learn them.

Comment: Ha, now that you are getting a handle on Promises it's time to move to `async/await` :)

Comment: I'll add that syntax as well.